# Best practices for placing SSL certificates for use in Apache 2?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, debian, ssl

In an environment where a handful of Apache servers are running a bunch of sites using SSL certificates for HTTPS, where should these certificates be placed? In Debian or Ubuntu, should all relevant files be put in /etc/apache2/ssl? Or is there some other location better suited for this? What security concerns should be addressed when choosing locations for these files for multiple websites on the same server?

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, I use Debian.

I place all private keys in `/etc/ssl/private` which has permission mode `0700`. I place all certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs` which has permission mode `0755`. The owner/group for both is root:root.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, your SSL key files should be readable only by a `root` user (you should issue two commands on them: `sudo chown root:root /path/to/your/keyfile.key` and `sudo chmod 600 /path/to/your/keyfile.key`). Your certificate files can be world-readable. And it's always a good idea to keep your keys and certificates outside your web-accessible document tree, `/etc/apache/ssl` should work well.

Answer (score 1):

The following best practices for placing SSL certificates have usually worked well for me:

1. `/usr/share/ca-certificates/domainname/` - Put the public `*.crt`
   files obtained from the CA authority here
2. `/etc/ssl/certs` - Create symbolic links to the files placed in the
   `/usr/share/ca-certificates/domainname/` directory
3. `/etc/ssl/private/private.key` - The private key is directly placed
   into this directory
4. `/opt/ssl/csr/domainname/domain.csr` - I place the original CSR in
   this directory for my future refeference.

If you are planning to use the SSL certificates for services such as Dovecot and Postfix you will also need the `*.pem` files. You can put those converted `*.pem` files in `/opt/ssl/csr/domainname/*.pem` and create a softlink to them into the `/etc/ssl/certs` directory.

Comment: The `*.crt` file should instead be placed into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/domainname/`. The symbolic link does usually not need to be created manually, at least on Debian you can just run `update-ca-certificates` and it will create it.